# Tubular surface around curve

Tags: sagemath

I need help with drawing tubular surface around curve. It is for my college project but we never used program like Sage so I don't know how to use it properly. We have Curve `c(t)=(2cos(t),2sin(t),0.5*t)` and I need to draw tubular surface around it. I need to calculate Frenet Trihedron and use it in some formula for tubular surface.

Here is the formula:

[image: formula]

My question is how do I make 3d projection out of this formula?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The Frenet trihedron for this helix can be calculated explicitly by hand, which then leads to an explicit parametrization for the tube. Is the question how to plot a parametric surface in Sage? (If so, it's likely someone here knows how, though the question may be sort of off-topic.)

Comment: Yes, my question is how to plot a parametric surface in Sage. Sorry if it is off-topic.